# Get Single value from the ModelSerializer

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

From CameraSerializer I want the flatten data right now I am getting data as an object

```
{...
 camera:{name:"camera_name"}
}
```

But I want

```
{...
 camera: "camera_name"
}
```

```
class CameraSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Camera
        fields = ['name']

class VehicleAccessRecordInformationCSVSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    # camera = CameraSerializer( read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = VehicleAccessRecordInformation
        fields = ['timestamp', 'license_plate_characters', 'vehicle_type', 'camera']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CharField

```py
class VehicleAccessRecordInformationCSVSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    camera = serializers.CharField(source="camera.name")
    class Meta:
        model = VehicleAccessRecordInformation
        fields = ['timestamp', 'license_plate_characters', 'vehicle_type', 'camera']
```